# Google marks emails sent from spreadsheet with MailApp.sendEmail as phishing scam

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a variation of Google's MailApp.sendEmail() script ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) to send emails to addresses in a spreadsheet. To test the script I am sending them to another gmail account. However, the emails are being marked with the message: This message may not have been sent by: foo@gmail.com. Is there any way to avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a consumer or enterprise account? If enterprise, it may be necessary to review how your domain is configured to work with gmail. (See [Issue 1278](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1278) for instance.)

Comment: It's a consumer account.

Comment: Looking at the SMTP message header, the difference between the header of the mail sent using the script & one from an email sent using gmail is that the message-id lists foo@google.com, whereas an email from my gmail account lists foo@ gmail.com.

Comment: I see those differences as well, but I'm not getting warnings. Have you read through [this troubleshooter from google](http://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2411000?hl=en)?

Comment: Yeah, I did. It turns out that the issue happened because I sent the email from one gmail account to another and I own both of them I think. I just tested out sending to someone else and there is no warning. Also, if I send a regular a regular email form one account to the other I get the same warning, so I guess it's some kind of bug/weirdness related to sending email between accounts.

Comment: Maybe - I was trying with one consumer and one enterprise account, so a little different. You should write up your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning isn't caused by the MailApp.sendMail() script. The phishing warning only shows up when I send email between two gmail accounts (both of which belong to me). It doesn't show up when I send email to other accounts using the MailApp.sendMail() script. The warning also appears when I send a standard gmail message from one account to the other, when the sending account is a consumer account, and the receiving account is a university account. The message does not appear on emails from other people's gmail addresses and does not appear on messages sent from my university account to my consumer account.